# ObservableCollection Remove/Add methods not work even if the item in the list

Tags: c#, collections

I have a little issue with adding and removing items from collection.

```
    private ObservableCollection<PrintDocumentSettingsModel> _AllPrintingFormats;
    public ObservableCollection<PrintDocumentSettingsModel> PrintingFormats
    {
        get
        {
            var formats = new ObservableCollection<PrintDocumentSettingsModel>(
                _AllPrintingFormats.Where(x => x.IsStandartPrinter == IsStandartPrinter));
            if (!formats.Contains(SelectedFormat))
                SelectedFormat = formats.FirstOrDefault();
            return formats;
        }
        set { _AllPrintingFormats = value; OnPropertyChanged("PrintingFormats"); }
    }

    private bool _IsStandartPrinter;
    public bool IsStandartPrinter
    {
        get { return _IsStandartPrinter; }
        set
        {
            _IsStandartPrinter = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsStandartPrinter");
            OnPropertyChanged("PrintingFormats");
        }
    }

    private void DeleteFormat()
    {
        if (SelectedFormat != null && SelectedFormat.IsEditable &&
            PrintingFormats.Contains(SelectedFormat))
        {
            PrintingFormats.Remove(SelectedFormat);
            OnPropertyChanged("PrintingFormats");
        }
    }
```

Method **DeleteFormat()** doesn't work even if the if statement returns true. But if I rewrite **DeleteFormat()** by replacing **PrintingFormats** with **_AllPrintingFormats** the method works properly.

```
    private void DeleteFormat()
    {
        if (SelectedFormat != null && SelectedFormat.IsEditable &&
            _AllPrintingFormats.Contains(SelectedFormat))
        {
            _AllPrintingFormats.Remove(SelectedFormat);
            OnPropertyChanged("PrintingFormats");
        }
    }
```

So what's the trick?

Comment: Obviously it does not work. The getter in `PrintingFormats` does not return `_AllPrintingFormats`. Instead it returns a new object which will be garbage collected later on. Any modification you make will be made on `var formats` in the `get` function which will not be reflected on `_AllPrintingFormats`. In `DeleteFormat()` use `_AllPrintingFormats` instead of `PrintingFormats`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not a nice way of writing properties. A property should return a private object in your class (whether explicitly or implicitly declared) except on some occasions where the property has nothing to do with any actual private member.

When you write this:

```
    get
    {
        var formats = new ObservableCollection<PrintDocumentSettingsModel>(
            _AllPrintingFormats.Where(x => x.IsStandartPrinter == IsStandartPrinter));
        if (!formats.Contains(SelectedFormat))
            SelectedFormat = formats.FirstOrDefault();
        return formats;
    }
    set { _AllPrintingFormats = value; OnPropertyChanged("PrintingFormats"); }
```

You are creating a new object called `formats` and returning a reference to that object. This has nothing to do with the actual private member `_AllPrintingFormats`. Therefore, when you call `PrintingFormats.Remove(SelectedFormat);` it will attempt the operation on `formats` which was declared and instantiated in the `get` function of `PrintingFormats`. This change is not reflected on `_AllPrintingFormats` as it's performed on a different object.

Furthermore, the change is completely useless since you will not hold any reference to `formats` and it will be garbage collected later on. The code you have is inefficient both on performance (creation of a new variable in `get` every time the property is called, AND using LINQ to create the variable) and on space (even after the reference on `formats` is released, it will not be cleaned directly by GC which means you will have multiple `formats` zombie objects waiting to be collected and occupying space).

By the way, using LINQ on a collection that is highly likely being accessed by multiple threads is not a very good idea as you can have race conditions. You have to understand that this line:

```
var formats = new ObservableCollection<PrintDocumentSettingsModel>(
        _AllPrintingFormats.Where(x => x.IsStandartPrinter == IsStandartPrinter));
```

Will NOT be determined right away. That is, you will not get the elements meeting the LINQ criteria on this call. This will be resolved ***after*** you return `formats` which means any change made by another thread will yield different results between the line and the actual use of `formats`

If you want to maintain the property and keep it as is, you can always do what you did in the second part of the question and directly use `_AllPrintingFormats`. However, I would recommend changing the `PrintingFormats` into:

```
get { return _AllPrintingFormats }
set 
{ 
    _AllPrintingFormats = value; 
    OnPropertyChanged("PrintingFormats"); 
}
```

And if you really need the LINQ query, you can do it on `PrintingFormats` instead of it being done by the property.

Comment: I see. How can I change the `get` function to return current collection?

Comment: @AlekseyPavlov `get { return _AllPrintingFormats; }`